# Get the maximum of 2 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

If i have a sql table with column like this
id  version   subversion
1   1            0
1   1            2
1   2            0
1   2            1

I want to get the latest version, in this case is 2.1.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Versions] ORDER BY [version] DESC, [subversion] DESC
```

should work fine... It works in MySQL atleast, and this is the basic MSSQL translation.

For reference, since the edit history isn't shown yet, my original query was:

```
SELECT * FROM [Versions] ORDER BY [version] DESC, [subversion] DESC LIMIT 1
```

Apparently MSSQL doesn't have the limit clause though, only [some workarounds](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=850&lngWId=5).

Comment: for MSSQL replace the Limit Clause at the end with

Select top 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table ORDER BY version DESC, subversion DESC
```